# Use PyTorch DistributedDataParallel with Hugging Face on Amazon SageMaker

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

Even for single-instance training, PyTorch DistributedDataParallel (DDP) is generally recommended over PyTorch DataParallel (DP) because DP's strategy is less performant and it uses more memory on the default device. (Per [this PyTorch forums thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cuda-out-of-memory-error-when-using-multi-gpu/72333))

Hugging Face [recommend](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/pytorch#distributed-training-and-mixed-precision) to run distributed training via the `python -m torch.distributed.launch` launcher, because their Trainer API supports DDP but will fall back to DP if you don't. (Per [this HF forums thread](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/multi-gpu-training/4021))

I recently ran in to this problem: scaling a HF training job from `p3.8xlarge` to `p3.16xlarge` increased memory consumption on (I think) one of the GPUs to the point where I had to significantly reduce batch size to avoid CUDA Out of Memory errors - basically losing all scaling advantage.

So the good news is for p3.16xl+ I can just [enable SageMaker Distributed Data Parallel](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/train#distributed-training) and the PyToch DLC will automatically [launch via torch.distributed for me](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit/blob/88ca48a831bf4f099d4c57f3c18e0ff92fa2b48c/src/sagemaker_pytorch_container/training.py#L23).

The bad news for use cases with smaller workloads or wanting to test before they scale up, is that SMDistributed [doesn't support all multi-GPU instance types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-parallel-intro.html#data-parallel-allreduce). No p3.8xl or g series, for example. I did try manually setting the `sagemaker_distributed_dataparallel_enabled` environment variable, but no joy.

So how else can we launch HF Trainer scripts with PyTorch DDP on SageMaker?

Answer (score 1):

Great question, thanks for asking! PyTorch DDP runs data parallel workers in multiple processes, that must be launched and managed by developers. DDP should be seen as a managed allreduce, more than a managed data-parallelism library, since it requires you to launch and manage the workers and even assigning resources to workers. In order to launch the DDP processes in a SageMaker Training job you have many options:

1. If you do multi-GPU, single-machine, you can use `torch.multiprocessing.spawn`, as shown in [this official PyTorch demo](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) (that is [broken](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) by the way)
2. If you do multi-GPU, single-machine, you can also use the [Ray Train](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/train/train.html) library to launch those processes. I was able to use it in a Notebook, but not in the DLC yet (recent library that is a bit rough to learn and make work, see [all my issues here](https://discuss.ray.io/u/lacruche/activity/topics)). Ray Train should work on multi-node too.
3. If you do multi-GPU, any-machine, you can use `torch.distributed.launch`, wrapped in a launcher script in shell or Python. Example here https://gitlab.aws.dev/cruchant/a2d2-segmentation/-/blob/main/3_2D-Seg-Audi-A2D2-Distributed-Training-DDP.ipynb
4. You can also launch those processes with the SageMaker MPI integration instead of `torch.distributed`. Unfortunately, we didn't create documentation for this, so no one uses it nor pitches it. But it looks cool, because it allows to run copies of your script directly in the EC2 machines without the need to invoke an intermediary PyTorch launcher. [Example here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/training/distributed_training/mpi_on_sagemaker/intro/mpi_demo.ipynb)

So for now, my recommendation would be to go the route (3), which is the closest to what the PyTorch community does, so provides easier development and debugging path.

**Notes**:

- PyTorch DDP evolves fast. In PT 1.10 `torch.distributed` is replaced by `torchrun`, and a [torchX](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-map-processes-to-gpu-in-ddp-and-how-to-launch-the-ddp-cluster/135253/4) tool is being created to...simplify things!).
- Not having to manage that mess is a reason why SageMaker Distributed Data Parallel is a great value prop: you only need to edit your script, and the SM service handles process creation. Unfortunately, as you point out, SMDP being limited to P3 and P4 training jobs seriously limits its use.
- Below are important PT DDP concepts to understand to alter single-GPU code into multi-machine code

  - Unlike Apache Spark, which takes care of workload partitioning on your behalf, Pytorch distributed training requires the user to assign specific pieces of work to specific GPUs. In the following section, we assume that we train on GPU.
  - In PyTorch DDP, each GPU runs a customized copy of you training code. A copy of the training code running on one GPU is generally called a *rank*, a *data parallel replica*, a *process*, a *worker*, but other names may exist.
  - For PyTorch DDP to launch a training cluster on the MxN GPUs spread over your M machines, you must specify to PyTorch DDP the number of machines you have and the number of processes to launch per machine. This is respectively done by the parameters `-nnodes` and `-nproc_per_node` of the `torch.distributed.launch` utility. You must run the `torch.distributed.lauch` once on each node of the training cluster. You can achieve this parallel command with multiple tools, for example with MPI or SageMaker Training as mentioned above. In order to establish the necessary handshakes and form a cluster, you must also specify in the `torch.distributed.launch` command `-node_rank`, which must take a unique machine ID between 0 and N-1 on each of the machines, and `-master_addr` and `-master_port`, optional if you run a single-machine cluster, which must be the same across all machines.
  - In the `init_process_group` DDP initialization method running from within each data parallel replica script, you must specify the world size and replica ID, respectively with the `world_size` and `rank` parameters. Hence you must have a way to communicate to each script a unique ID, generally called the *global rank*. The global rank can help you personalize the work done by each GPU, for example saving a model just from one card, or running validation only in one card. In a cluster composed of 3 machines having 4 GPUs each, global ranks would range from 0 to 11. Within a machine, in order to assign DDP data parallel replicas to available GPUs, the script running in each replica must be assigned a GPU ID, unique within the machine it's running on. This is called the local rank and can be set as an argument by the PyTorch DDP `torch.distributed.launch`. In a cluster composed of 3 machines having 4 GPUs each, on each machine the DDP processes would have local ranks ranging from 0 to 3